# Linux SLE11 SPC3 Mail::IMAPClient

Tags: linux, perl, suse, imapclient

i am trying to get the imapclient on my OS but it wont work. I added the perl repository like so:

```
     zypper ar -f -n perl http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/devel:/languages:/perl/SLE_11_SP2 Perl
```

and i get the right output where it says the repository is added.

but when i use zypper to add the imapclient like this

```
    zypper install -y "perl(MAIL::IMAPClient)"
```

I get:

```
    zypper install -y "perl(MAIL::IMAPClient)"
    Refreshing service 'susecloud'.
    Retrieving repository 'perl' metadata [done]
    Building repository 'perl' cache [done]
    Retrieving repository 'perl' metadata [error]
    Repository 'perl' is invalid.
    [|] Valid metadata not found at specified URL(s)
    Please check if the URIs defined for this repository are pointing to a valid 
    repository.
    Warning: Disabling repository 'perl' because of the above error.
    Loading repository data...
    Reading installed packages...
    'perl(MAIL::IMAPClient)' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
    No provider of 'perl(MAIL::IMAPClient)' found.
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: how about `cpan MAIL::IMAPClient`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>cpan install MAIL::IMAPClient
```

or harder

```
>cpan
cpan> force install MAIL::IMAPClient
```

or

```
>ppm install MAIL::IMAPClient
```

or with GUI

```
>ppm
*choose package and install via gui*
```

Link: [MAIL::IMAPClient](http://search.cpan.org/~plobbes/Mail-IMAPClient-3.35/lib/Mail/IMAPClient.pod)

Comment: Thanks it worked perfectly is cpan and ppm another installation tool like zypper?

Comment: IMHO i think zypper is a kind of repo installer for SuSe? cpan is the basic modul installation kit for perl.. ppm is a utility according to active state perl, but provides only limited modules which are 100% compatible for active state perl..